# Export customers and their passwords from Magento CE 1.9.0.1 to another platform?

Tags: password

So at my workplace, there's been a decision to potentially move away from Magento if we can find a suitable alternative. The rationale is basically because it takes up most of my time and it's had a few niggles over the last few months. Nothing that is a showstopper tbh though and there aren't a lot of issues, but lots of demands to have this and that. I'm the only one who looks after, maintains and supports it (aside from some help with product updates), along with anything else related to our website, or promotion of it.

So I've been looking at a few options and the MD is keen to not have to make customers on the new system have to activate an account or set a new password on the new system when we transfer the customer data over. I've seen that a few platforms will allow importing of customers and their passwords, as long as the passwords are clear text. However, this is not possible to get from Magento because it's MD5 encrypted and you can't get back the clear password once encrypted.

I've seen an extension from liteextension that will migrate passwords from a Magento store to Prestashop, which manages to migrate the MD5 hash password over to Prestashop (which also uses MD5). However, that's if we decide to use Prestashop! I just wonder if there's any other options for me to be able to migrate passwords across for another system.

Everything I've read thus far, points to generally just getting customers to create a new password on the system. Sorry for the long post!

Thanks,

M

Comment: In regards to the password, I think the only option you will have is finding a shop system that uses the same encryption method when checking the passwords. Since you can not get the actual passwords from your hash to encrypt them again a different way. An alternative would be to not import the passwords, but send every customer an automated reset password email after you've imported them and gone live with your new system

Comment: As a customer, I would be happy to reset my password if a store owner asked me to. It shows me they actually care about the security of my account details.

Migrating users and "making it easy" for them so they don't have to enter a new password is exactly the kind of thing a Marketing Director would think. I suggest you diplomatically inform them that they are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been decided that we'll stick with Magento for now due to what it offers us and what we will lose if we try to find another solution.  It'll be hassle too.

Thanks!